# HLS / Media Source Extensions <video> with muted & autoplay freezes on first frame on mobiles

Tags: html, reactjs, html5-video, http-live-streaming, next.js

I attempted to add a Hero background video to our website. It's being served from mux.com.

I use it with HLS, but for Chrome it uses Media Source Extensions from what I gather.

I know that for HTML5 video to auto play, it has to be muted also, and I have both parameters over there.

Apparently, on Android Chrome I get behaviour where it freezes on the first frame (black), but doesn't continue and I cannot trace why.

In case of freezing, it still does load the video, just that it's not getting autoplayed.

I am out of clues.

---

Isolation sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/32yky6x7mq

https://32yky6x7mq.codesandbox.io/

In my attempts, I have reduced this down to simple HTML app with Hls.js library and basic `<video>` tag where it breaks on mobiles.

---

**How do I get the video to autoplay on mobiles?**

P.S. To see exactly what I have tried, please see edit history, as I have been trying lots of things.

Comment: HLS should play in the browser natively (at least, more recent ones) without needing MSE, have you tried accessing the stream directly in a vanilla `<video>` tag?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal I just tried, and no, it doesn't load natively on Chrome 70, at least. After update to 71 (latest), it doesn't work either: https://codesandbox.io/s/pkvm66o0rj

Comment: Ok, after more debugging, it just seems that the autoplay doesn't work on mobiles with HLS...

Comment: Ah-ha, it seems to be related with Android Chrome's Data Saver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my device specifically, Android Chrome, it's caused by **Data Saver**.

Disabling **Data Saver**, the video autoplays.
It's paradoxical, because with **Data Saver** I expect for the video to not be loaded at all, but it's getting loaded and the autoplay gets interrupted instead - resulting in more waste.

Possibly, there are other settings out there in the wild that prevent autoplay, for instance, couldn't find the exact reasons why iOS is not working. There are hints about `playsinline` attribute, which I have not tested yet. (Will update when I do)

Worth noting, is `Feature-Policy` header too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy
It didn't help me in my scenario, but it can probably be related with autoplay in other scenarios.